# How to process the result of a view?

Tags: 7, views

I'm working on a publication database, the result should be something like this: http://www.bmj.com/content/350/bmj.h2747 As you can see in authors list and in Author affiliations block, only unique workplaces are listed as footnotes of authors.

I'd like to figure out how this can be reproduced with views (or with other technique)? I created a content types for authors and can filter them for a given article in a view. But the result should be massively process: I have to filter the unique workplaces and assign them to authors in the display.

So as the title asks: How (and where - in the view?) can I process the result of this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views can be great for some things, but sometimes it can add more complication then it is worth. Trying to achieve this in views seems like it could be one of those situations.

If you are familiar with coding, it might be easier to process the list of authors, grab the entity_reference from them, create an array from those where you don't repeat the values and then output the numbers associated with each value.

If looking to do this solely in views, you could use https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7 to grab the results and process them and then output the rows as desired.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will do it with views. At least querying the necessary records seems to be easier with it.