# Alter the result of a view with regrouping, supplementing original values

Tags: 7, views

I tried to create a [similar question before](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163402/how-to-process-the-result-of-a-view) but it was unclear, hopefully I can narrow it a little bit:

So I'd like to create an authors-article webpage, such as: http://www.bmj.com/content/350/bmj.h2747 As you can see  workplaces (affiliations) are displayed as footnotes in a separate block, after the list of authors.

I'm working on reproducing something similar with views. I have two content types (article and author) and authors are connected to articles with a node reference field. All the necessary data have been queried with a view and I'd like to alter $view->result with the help of a [views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) hook:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render (&$view) {

    if ($view->name == 'publi_author_views' && $view->current_display == 'panel_pane_1') {

        $workplaces = array();
        $workplaces_clean = array();
        $workplace_display = "";
        $workplace_count = "1";
        $author_display = "";

        foreach($view->result as $authors) {
            $workplace = $authors->field_field_publi_workplace[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
            $workplaces[] = $workplace;
        }

        unset($authors);
        unset($workplace);

        $workplaces_clean = array_unique($workplaces);

        foreach($workplaces_clean as $wp_clean) {
            foreach($view->result as $authors) {
                $author = $authors->node_title;
                $workplace = $authors->field_field_publi_workplace[0]['rendered']['#markup'];

                if ($wp_clean == $workplace) {
                    $authors->node_title = $author." <sup>".$workplace_count."</sup>";

                    $authors->field_field_fake_title[0]['rendered'] = array(
                        '#markup' => $author." <sup>".$workplace_count."</sup>",
                        '#access' => TRUE,
                    );
                }

            }

            $workplace_display .= "<sup>".$workplace_count."</sup> ".$wp_clean;
            $workplace_count = $workplace_count+1;
        }
    }
   }
```

I have two problems:

1. How can I add to authors the number in superscript? As you can see in the code above I appended it to $authors->node_title, but it doesn't display HTML-entities. Then I created a "fake" field (field_field_fake_title) but it hasn't been rendered.
2. How can I add the list of workplaces to a separate block? I created the $workplace_display variable with the necessary HTML-code but I wasn't able to put it into $view->result since it doesn't really belong to any of the rows.

Comment: You can use Global :PHP field and configure "Output code" using $row value like $row->title

Comment: This is an example where just using Views and one-direction relationships gets painful. Considering using the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module, or using a computed field on the article to store other items of interest about the article. Either approach would help you do to less logic in your Views.

Comment: After all I used views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) here: I did the necessary manipulations with the data of $view then rebuilt the $output inserting the new result into it.